# Using pandas to_sql to ignore bad lines on writing to database

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, bigdata, pandas-to-sql

I have a pretty huge dataset that needs to be uploaded for database (in my case Postgres). If I use standard to_sql with chunksize of 5000, there will be some bad lines because some data is corrupted. However if I would try to catch exception and iterate over each line to catch them, it would take quite a bit time, iterating over each line takes quite a bit of time.

What I try to do:

```
def insert_do_nothing_on_conflicts(sqltable, conn, keys, data_iter):
    from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert
    from sqlalchemy import table, column
    columns = []
    for c in keys:
        columns.append(column(c))
    if sqltable.schema:
        table_name = '{}.{}'.format(sqltable.schema, sqltable.name)
    else:
        table_name = sqltable.name
    mytable = table(table_name, *columns)
    insert_stmt = insert(mytable).values(list(data_iter))
    do_nothing_stmt = insert_stmt.on_conflict_do_nothing(index_elements=['timestamp'])
    conn.execute(do_nothing_stmt)

def write_to_db(filename):
    chunksize = 10 ** 6
    chunk_count=0
    for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize,on_bad_lines='skip',header = None,encoding='windows-1251'):

        while chunk_count<=5:
            chunk_count+=1
            continue
        i=0
        while i < len(chunk) + 1:
            #try:
            chunk[i:i+5000].to_sql(name='test_table_2',schema='kkt', con=engine_postgres, index=False, if_exists='append',method='insert_do_nothing_on_conflicts')
            i+=5000
            if i % 100000 ==0:
                print (i//5000, (len(chunk)//5000)+2)
        chunk_count+=1
```

But I receive error

ValueError: Invalid parameter method: insert_do_nothing_on_conflicts

Searched all the web cannot find the answer. Method should work and it presents in some code. It does not matter which method I put in code they all do not work. I need a quick answer to that.

Comment: What is a good line and what is a bad line? [mre]

Comment: Does it matter? I need to skip all errors: incorrect length of line, incorrect datatype etc., etc. What I need is a way to quickly write to DB skipping all errors.

Comment: remove the quotes around 'insert_do_nothing_on_conflicts' when you specify it as value of method.

Answer (score 0):

*Not an answer yet, obviously, but too long for a comment.*

---

*"Searched all the web cannot find the answer."*

In that case, let's get back to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html?highlight=valueerror#ValueError):

> ***Exception ValueError:** Raised when an operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value, and the situation is not described by a more precise exception such as IndexError.*

But also

> *Passing arguments of the wrong type (e.g. passing a list when an int is expected) should result in a TypeError, but passing arguments with the wrong value (e.g. a number outside expected boundaries) should result in a **ValueError**.*

---

*"Method should work"*

How are you so sure? According to the above, at least one argument passed to `insert_do_nothing_on_conflicts` either has an incorrect datatype or an incorrect value.

Need more information to continue:

- representative input data (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
- What line is the error raised?
- There may be a more complete error traceback that could be useful.